# Is there a way to verify all the cells in a row meet the same criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to vba and trying to automate some data analysis. Within the raw data, I have formatted cells to highlight those between two user input criteria. Now I need to find the rows where all the cells in that row are highlighted. I tried the following. Pardon formatting I'm on mobile.

```
Sub Hold()

    Dim cell as range
    Dim rowdata as range
    Dim s as long
    Dim rc as long
    Dim n as Boolean

    rc = range("C10", range("C10").end(xldown)).rows.count

    For s = 0 to rc
        Set rowdata = range("C10", range("C10").end(xltoright)).offset(s , 0)
            For each cell in RowData
                If cell.interior.color <> 11389944 Then
                    n = false 
                    Exit for
                End if 
            Next cell

        If n = false then 
            Rowdata.font.color = rgbred
        Else 
            Rowdata.font.color = rgbgreen
        End if
    Next s
End Sub
```

I manually searched to find a row where all the cells are highlighted within the row. As I debugged, I expected the font to change to green. It did not. I noticed the second `if` statement had `n = false` even though I expected it to be true since in that row `cell.interior.color = 11389944`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Instead of checking for the color - check for the same logic you used in your conditional formatting. Can you share what rule was used to format the cells in the first place? That is prob the better way to go

Comment: Please get in the habit of indenting your code - makes it much more readable. One thing is that `n` can never be `True`.

Comment: The default value for a boolean like `n` is `false` - you never set it to `True` ...

Comment: @urdearboy to format in the first place, `If cell.value >= CriteriaMinimum  AND cell.value <= CriteriaMamimum Then cell.interior.color = 11389944`

Comment: @SJR I apologize for the lack of indentation. I was posting this question via mobile. Why could `n` not be `True` if the condition is met `n = false` If the condition is not met the `n` would have to be `True` as the only other remaining option. I thought boolean was either true or false.

Comment: It does not automatically become `True` if the `False` condition is not met, that's not how it works, you have to explicitly set it.

Comment: @SJR Thank you for that clarification, I didn't know it had to be explicitly set.